# i want to render a file in browser using react (the file is coming from server )

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, postman

**What i want do is ,when i click a on button a file coming from server will get displayed in browser**

`I tried it using postman when i send filename my sever returns html file and it get displayd in postman as response but i don't know how should i display in browser using react js`

but when i fetch in react js i get error `VM13094:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

or also don't know how to display in browser i tried to do diffrent things but can't figure it out

Comment: Check your content-type in the response header. Is should be  "content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8". I suspect the content-type being served is application/json

Comment: @Sherawat your question is very broad and has no code. Just youtube it - "how to fetch and display data in React", then you can come back and ask about a particular code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.